# GitHub actions not blocking PR with required step in skipped state

Tags: github, github-actions

I have the GitHub action that should only be ran when the commit message contains 'test_api'. However, I do want it to be a required check for the PR to be able to get merged. For some reason this is not picked up, and it does not make any sense to me.

```
jobs:
  api-tests:
    if: contains(github.event.commits[0].message, '[test_api]')
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    ...
```

[PR ready to merge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yf5j5.png)

[Branch protection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FmUa.png)

Comment: Why not throwing an error (forcing a failure) to break the workflow if the the message doesn't contains 'test-api'?

Answer (score 0):

It says that tests were skipped - that means this is not true:

```
if: contains(github.event.commits[0].message, '[test_api]')
```

Unless you have more actions in the workflow.

Comment: I know these were skipped. I want them to skip. However I am still able to merge the PR when they are in skipped mode, which is highly undesired.

Answer (score 0):

I would force a failure if the condition isn't true.

```yaml
jobs:
  api-tests:
    if: contains(github.event.commits[0].message, '[test_api]')
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      ...
    
  not-api-tests:
    if: "!contains(github.event.commits[0].message, '[test_api]')"
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2.3.4
    - name: Fail the job
      run: exit 1
```

*Note: This should work on all 3 platforms (ubuntu, macos, windows).*

I tested it [here (committing with [test_api])](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/actions/runs/1893478311) and [here (forcing the error with another commit message)](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/actions/runs/1893482577). The workflow implementation can be found [here](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/47-force-failure.yml).

Comment: Hey, I indeed did the same for now but I really don't like the idea. It displays all of the test as failing now. Additionally, I have to add logic to compensate for the main branch where it should always run, regardless of the commit message.

It's so strange, if you check the screenshots it clearly shows that the `api_test` is marked required. Yet it does not block when skipped.